# Excel vlook up function in R for data frame

Tags: r

I have a problem with a data frame and hope to find help here.   The initial data frame (let's call it df1) contains an ID number, that might be repeated several times and might not be in order.

```
>df1
      ID
1   5468
2   5468
3   8896
4   8896
```

I would like to use this ID, to look up the corresponding country in another data frame (df2), that looks something like that:

```
>df2
    ID     country
1   5468   USA
2   8896   Canada
```

and add the country in the initial data frame. Note that every ID only appears once in the second data frame but can have multiple appearances in the first data frame. Basically  I am looking for something similar to the Excel "vlookup" function, just for R.

I would appreciate any help very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(5468,8896), each=2))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(5468,8896), country=c("USA","Canada"))

merge(df1, df2)
    ID country
1 5468     USA
2 5468     USA
3 8896  Canada
4 8896  Canada
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match()`.

Like if the first one is `dataset1$ID[n]`, and the second is `dataset2$ID`

Then `dataset2[match(dataset1$ID[n],dataset2$ID,2]`

But for most purposes the answer James gave is way better, but match is more analogous to vlookup if you really want that.

Answer (score 1):

This uses an environment lookup and so on larger data sets this may be much faster than any other solution:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(5468,8896), each=2))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(5468,8896), country=c("USA","Canada"))

library(qdap)
df1$country <- lookup(df1[, 1], df2)

## binary operator for lookup
##  df1$country <- df1[, 1] %l% df2  

## > df1
##     ID country
## 1 5468     USA
## 2 5468     USA
## 3 8896  Canada
## 4 8896  Canada
```